# Blazor WASM online/active users

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I'm developing a taxi management app with **Blazor WASM + Asp.NET API** and I want to know which of my drivers are online/available, so I need to know about the connection state of the drivers(online/offline), but I'm quite new to Webassembly and I can't find something useful on this topic.

Is this even possible, knowing that Blazor WASM runs on Client side?

Comment: Sounds like something a server would do.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 you're right, but I hope that there's also a way for WASM.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer-- I'm not an expert in any of this.  I'm open to learning I'm wrong-- but I doubt it! :D

Knowing when someone comes ONLINE is simple. . . you can add an ID to a list of active users through your API.  But what happens when someone just closes their browser or turns off their device?  Dead clients post no API requests.  Even in server-hosted Blazor, it's not that easy to detect exactly when someone has gone OFFLINE.

Where's your API hosted?  Do you have access to timers?  **Can you send some kind of identifier with a requirement to send a keep-alive notification every 10 seconds or so, and remove a user from the list if you don't get it?**

I'm interested in how it goes for you, because my company also has a bus department, and I'll be adding similar capabilities soon.